# Threaded timer, interrupting a sleep (stopping it)

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer

I'm wanting a reasonably reliable threaded timer, so I've written a timer object that fires a std::function on a thread.  I would like to give this timer the ability to stop before it gets to the next tick; something you can't do with ::sleep (at least I don't think you can).

So what I've done is put a condition variable on a mutex.  If the condition times out, I fire the event.  If the condition is signalled the thread is exited.  So the Stop method needs to be able to get the thread to stop and/or interrupt its wait, which I think is what it's doing right now.

There are problems with this however.  Sometimes the thread isn't joinable() and sometimes the condition is signalled *after* its timeout but before it's put into its wait state.

How can I improve this and make it robust?

The following is a full repo.  The wait is 10 seconds here but the program should terminate immediately as the Foo is created and then immediately destroyed.  It does sometimes but mostly it does not.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

class Timer
{
public:

    Timer() {}

    ~Timer()
    {           
        Stop();
    }

    void Start(std::chrono::milliseconds const & interval, std::function<void(void)> const & callback)
    {   
        Stop();

        thread = std::thread([=]()
        {
            for(;;)
            {
                auto locked = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);
                auto result = terminate.wait_for(locked, interval);

                if (result == std::cv_status::timeout)
                {
                    callback();
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void Stop()
    {       
        terminate.notify_one();

        if(thread.joinable())
        {
            thread.join();
        }
    }

private:

    std::thread thread;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable terminate;
};

class Foo
{
public: 

    Foo()
    {
        timer = std::make_unique<Timer>();
        timer->Start(std::chrono::milliseconds(10000), std::bind(&Foo::Callback, this));
    }

    ~Foo()
    {

    }

    void Callback()
    {
        static int count = 0;

        std::ostringstream o;

        std::cout << count++ << std::endl;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Timer> timer;
};


int main(void)
{
    {
        Foo foo;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Somewhere you need a variable protected by the mutex that stores whether or not the thread is supposed to stop. Condition variables are stateless -- it is your responsibility to maintain the state of the thing you're waiting for (called the "predicate"). Basically, you've missed the point of condition variables. Your `Stop` function notifies the thread. But it hasn't changed any condition that the thread is waiting for! Notice that the mutex doesn't protect anything. This is just totally wrong.

Comment: Updated the code as I missed out the else...!

Comment: Why `return` on a spurious wakeup? (Same problem. You have no way to know whether you should wakeup or not because you have no predicate to check.)

Comment: What other kinds of wakeup are there?  There's timeout and user signalled the wait.  Can the OS wake it up for other reasons?

Comment: You still don't understand condition variables. They are stateless. You are imagining that you will only be woken up in some particular set of states, but they don't have states. It's your responsibility to track the state. There is no "signalled" state, so you have no way to tell if there was a signal.

Comment: If you think there is some particular state in which you will be woken up, answer me this -- in your code, what variable holds this state? In my code, it's `stop`. What is it in yours? Tracking state is your responsibility. The call to `notify_one` doesn't change the state to a signaled state.

Comment: No, I don't understand.  wait_for returns cv_status, which returns either no_timeout or timeout.  That's all I need to know to stop it in one of two cases:  it timed out (excellent, fire the event), it didn't timeout (it was woken up for some other reason, probably a caller calling Stop, so terminate).

Comment: If you're okay with making decisions based on a "probably" and have code that happens to work right some of the time, go ahead and don't bother to check.

Comment: I'm *trying to understand it*.  Stop the snark.  It's completely unnecessary.

Comment: You need some way to know whether the thing the thread is waiting for has happened or not. That is the state. Condition variables are stateless. Maintaining that state is your responsibility. The condition variable cannot assure that a wakeup has occurred without tracking the state itself (how else would it do that?) and it, by design, doesn't do that.

Comment: If you're thinking "why doesn't the condition variable somehow make sure that it only wakes me if the event has happened", you're basically asking why condition variables are stateless. It's a design decision to make them as light as possible. 99% of the time you have to track the state anyway, so why have duplicate state 99% of the time?

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh I see what you mean about state now.  I misunderstood what condition_variable was actually doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my comment. You forgot to implement the state of the thing the thread is waiting for, leaving the mutex nothing to protect and the thread nothing to wait for. Condition variables are stateless -- your code must track the state of the thing whose change you're notifying the thread about.

Here's the code fixed. Notice that the mutex protects `stop`, and `stop` is the thing the thread is waiting for.

```
    class Timer
    {
    public:

        Timer() {}

        ~Timer()
        {           
            Stop();
        }

        void Start(std::chrono::milliseconds const & interval,
            std::function<void(void)> const & callback)
        {   
            Stop();

            {
                auto locked = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);    
                stop = false;
            }

            thread = std::thread([=]()
            {
                auto locked = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);    

                while (! stop) // We hold the mutex that protects stop
                {
                    auto result = terminate.wait_for(locked, interval);

                    if (result == std::cv_status::timeout)
                    {
                        callback();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        void Stop()
        {    
            {     
                // Set the predicate
                auto locked = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);
                stop = true;
            }

            // Tell the thread the predicate has changed
            terminate.notify_one();

            if(thread.joinable())
            {
                thread.join();
            }
        }

    private:

        bool stop; // This is the thing the thread is waiting for
        std::thread thread;
        std::mutex mutex;
        std::condition_variable terminate;
    };
```

Comment: I had this before with stop as std::atomic<bool>.  I assumed I needed the mutex just to get *terminate* to sit and wait or timeout.  So why do I need to protect *stop* with the mutex?

Comment: @Robinson To avoid the race condition of it changing state just as you enter `wait_for`. You need the mutex to protect the predicate, that's why it's passed to `wait_for`. You are missing the whole point of condition variables, which is to provide an atomic "unlock and wait" operation.

Comment: Oh, I see.  How silly of me.  Of course.  Thank you.

Comment: This is the whole reason condition variables exist.

Comment: With your code I get "locked" ... is a deleted function so it won't compile.  So I pass it by reference to capture [=, &locked] and it compiles but I get a runtime error at wait_for (OPERATION_NOT_PERMITTED).

Comment: I do not get why Stop() function call is necessary in the Start function

Comment: @Csuszmusz It just makes the code easier to use. It could be improved.

Comment: I have written a class similar to yours, but find that the object is slow to destroying, the stop function needs to acquire the lock to notify that we are quitting, but the sleeping thread only releases the lock at the time of spurious wakeup or sleep time out, which blocks our stop function quite a period. Do you have any idea to enhance? Thanks

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin The sleeping thread releases the lock while it sleeps, that's why `locked` is passed to `wait_for`. This code does hold the lock during the callback though. You can change that if you wish.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for your explanation, I should have remembered wrong